Trailing Slash on website requiring multiple trailing slashes
I'm working on a personal website and something that is just irritating is the location to any of my subpages is adding two extra trailing slashes.
For example I have a different folder for an about page subdomain but when opening it on a website it shows up as ..../About/abt (About being the folder name and abt being the actual html file). Is there any way to make it only show the first folder name instead of also having the subdomain for the abt.html file?

For clarity, what you're talking about are subdirectories, not subdomains.
If you rename the file in your about subdirectory from abt.html to index.html, your web server should serve it when you visit example.com/about/. The MDN Web Docs has a Getting Started with HTML guide that explains more.
